# wordpress how can I insert a link on login page

Tags: wordpress

I want to insert a link in login page in between the Login button and the password field, Is it possible ? if possible which action i need to hook ? I just want to insert a DIV and a link in between the Login submit button and the Passowrord feild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hook called login_form that is placed in the right place

```
add_action(
  'login_form',
  function() {
    echo 'howdy ho!';
  }
);
```

Comment: You have to mention the source of the code: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/113414

Comment: Not sure if you and that user are the same (although, it's almost a copy/paste Question), but see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667)